# sem_init on OS X

Tags: c, macos, pthreads, semaphore

I am working on some code which uses the pthread and semaphore libraries. The `sem_init` function works fine on my Ubuntu machine, but on OS X the `sem_init` function has absolutely no effect. Is there something wrong with the library or is there a different way of doing it? This is the code I am using to test.

```
sem_t sem1;
sem_t sem2;
sem_t sem3;
sem_t sem4;
sem_t sem5;
sem_t sem6;

sem_init(&sem1, 1, 1);
sem_init(&sem2, 1, 2);
sem_init(&sem3, 1, 3);
sem_init(&sem4, 1, 4);
sem_init(&sem5, 1, 5);
sem_init(&sem6, 1, 6);
```

The values appear to be random numbers, and they do not change after the `sem_init` call.

Comment: You should test the return value of `sem_init`.

Comment: Note that in Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10) at least, `sem_init()`, `sem_destroy()` and `sem_getvalue()` are marked 'deprecated' and generate compiler warnings as a result.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, no. It cannot work in Mac OS X Yosemite(10.10.1).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413785/sem-init-on-os-x and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641126/posix-semaphores-on-mac-os-x-sem-timedwait-alternative

Your options are to reimplement the needed api using GCD semaphore, mach semaphore, mutex + pthread condition vars, or mutex + pipes (to block and signal as needed)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Unnamed semaphores are not supported, you need to use named semaphores.

To use named semaphores instead of unnamed semaphores, use `sem_open` instead of `sem_init`, and use `sem_close` and `sem_unlink` instead of `sem_destroy`.

Comment: Wow.  `<semaphore.h>` declares `sem_init` so that it compiles properly on OS X, but it returns -1 with `errno` set to `ENOSYS` (function not implemented).

Comment: Ok, now I'm looking for a good example of semaphores using C++ boost libraries. I have heard that is a robust implementation

Comment: `sem_getvalue()` doesn't work either......
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655153/sem-getvalue-dysfunctionality-in-mac-os-x-c/16655541#16655541

Answer (score 26):

A better solution (these days) than named semaphores on OS X is Grand Central Dispatch's dispatch_semaphore_t. It works very much like the unnamed POSIX semaphores.

Initialize the semaphore:

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1); // init with value of 1
```

Wait & post (signal):

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
...
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
```

Destroy:

```
dispatch_release(semaphore);
```

The header file is well documented and I found it quite easy to use.

Comment: GCD semaphore is GCD level feature. Theoretically, it can cause some issue if combined with pthread level.

Comment: @Eonil can you elaborate? What sort of issues could you have?

Comment: @MichaelDorst Wrong question. Basically, you should not use API exposed on different abstraction to control another abstraction unless they are explicitly designed to work together. Even if you know all the details and they are working now because implementation details can change later. If you have no evidence of interoperability, you should assume such usage as unsafe due to potential issues. And there's no evidence that GCD API will work as expected for POSIX thread.

Comment: @MichaelDorst Correct question would be "What's the evidence of GCD APIs would work for POSIX thread?" No evidence means unsafe.

Comment: @MichaelDorst GCD is not an "extension" or "utility" feature to aid pthread. It's a separated and opaque abstraction that does not depend on implementation details.

Comment: @MichaelDorst Just remember that one thread can run multiple GCD queues and a GCD queue can run on any thread except main queue. Stopping a GCD queue doesn't guarantee stopping a POSIX thread. Using GCD API to control POSIX thread is just a non-sense.

Comment: @eonil While I agree they're different levels of abstraction, what's the concrete scenario in which the behavior when using GCD semaphore would be different than if pthread semaphore was used? It's true that when using GCD one should not care about the underlying thread, but there is no note that GCD primitives cannot be used outside a dispatch queue, nor that pthread primitives should not be used inside a dispatch queue. In fact I believe one of the main points of dispatch_semaphore is to allow coordination between GCD and non-GCD contexts

Comment: Ah I see you asked this question on apple forum and got a similar answer :) https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/113155

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of sem_init in the source then it just returns an error, while some of the other bsd fns like sem_open still have implementation.

Both the "deprecated" posix fns and libdispatch/GCD call from userspace using fns like semphore_create and semaphore_wait. You can use these directly if you want an old-style sema that always uses the kernel/OS, but you're better with ones like from GCD that uses atomic counters internally and only calls the kernel/OS if it has to wait.

https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/a1babec6b135d1f35b2590a1990af3c5c5393479/bsd/kern/posix_sem.c