# POSIX semaphores: synchronization problem

Tags: c, synchronization, posix, semaphore

I have a problem with synchronization using posix semaphores. Here's the code I wrote

```
sem_t *sem1, *sem2;

void* test1() {
    int rv;

    while(1) {
        rv = sem_wait(sem1);
        printf("sem_wait(&sem1) = %d\n",rv);
        printf("test1\n");

        rv = sem_post(sem2);
        printf("sem_post(&sem2) = %d\n\n",rv);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* test2() {

    while(1) {

        rv = sem_wait(sem2);
        printf("sem_wait(&sem2) = %d\n",rv);
        printf("test2\n");

        rv = sem_post(sem1);
        printf("sem_post(&sem1) = %d\n\n",rv);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

pthread_t t1,t2;

sem1 = sem_open("sem1", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1);

if (sem1 == SEM_FAILED){
    perror("sem1_init");
    sem_close(sem1);
    return;
}   

sem2 = sem_open("sem2", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
if (sem2 == SEM_FAILED){
    perror("sem2_init");
    sem_close(sem1);
    sem_close(sem2);
    return;
}

pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &test1, NULL);
pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &test2, NULL);

pthread_join(t1, NULL);
pthread_join(t2, NULL);

return 0;
}
```

What I expected is that, since I initialized `sem1` to 1 and `sem2` to 0, `test1` would be the first function to run, and then they will alternate till the end of time. 
Instead it's not working, I mean in the log I read many times "test1", many times "test2", for a while alternated and then again without any order. 
Can someone tell me where is my error?

ps. don't know if it can be useful but I'm running MacOSX 10.6.7

---

EDIT: 
I updated my code, removing all calls to `sem_init` and `sem_getvalue` (both not present under MacOS), using `sem_open` to init the semaphores and it seems to work. 
I found, however, a strange problem, probably because of my miscomprehension of `sem_open` call: every time I restart the program if I reuse the same name for semaphores I get the error `File exists`. How can I force to reuse the same identifier? 
Besides. according to man pages, `sem_wait` should return 0 if successful, -1 if not. What does it mean if I receive 1 (this happen always in `test2` )?

Comment: Firstly, compile the program with warnings enabled. Also, check the return value of all your calls for errors. Then, see if e.g this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413785/sem-init-on-os-x and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136181/program-using-semaphores-runs-fine-on-linux-unexpected-results-on-mac-osx is your problem.

Comment: Seconding @nos here: **Check for errors after all library calls.** Just because your code compiles, that does not mean it will run without errors; ignoring error information is inviting a shot in the foot.

Comment: @nos Wow, if I could give a -1 to Apple for not implementing this, I would.  :P  (And of course, I agree: always check for errors...)

Comment: asveikau was right, it seems there are not `sem_init` and `sem_getvalue` under MacOS... I expected at least a warning for this, instead I even receive code completion... Anyway, I edited the original post with some corrections. Not sure this is a real solution to the problem but it seems to work. Check if some of you knows the answer to the question I added at the end of the post

Comment: I think all you have to do is remove the O_EXCL argument from your call to sem_open.  That flag explicitly tells it to fail if the semaphore name exists.

Comment: @Summit Guy: If he removes `O_EXCL`, then it will open the existing semaphore objects with indeterminate starting values.

Comment: @Saphrosit: Your updated code works fine for me (on the first run).  Named semaphores persist in the kernel after your program dies.  You need to call `sem_unlink` to fully remove the semaphore.  If your program is only terminated by signals such as Ctrl-C (SIGINT), then you need to set a signal handler with `signal(2)` or `sigaction(2)` that will call `sem_unlink` before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is for the two functions to alternate, you should just use a single semaphore.

When one of your threads gets scheduled, for example t1, it locks sem1 and then keeps it and runs in a while loop until it gets interrupted. Because it's not doing a sem_post(&sem1), it doesn't give control to the other thread.

---

Update:  Looking at this again, this code should work.  I think the sem_init not being implemented on OSX is probably your issue.

---

Update:  To answer your question about sem_wait returning 1, it looks like the real error value is returned in `errno`.  If the return value `!= 0`, then check there.  My shot in the dark guess would be EINTR is what you are seeing.

Comment: Absolutely not sure about that. When t1 starts it calls `sem_wait(&sem1)`. `sem1` was initialized to 1, so `sem1`'s value is set to 0 and t1 enter the crical section (or simply pass over the `sem_wait` call). It prints "test1", then `sem_post(&sem2)`, setting `sem2`'s value to 1 (so that t2 may enter in the critical section if it was waiting at the semaphore, else it'll enter when it reaches that point). When t1 starts again the cycle it'll find `sem1` to 0 ('cause no `sem_post` where called on `sem1`) and it starts wait on the semaphore queue until t2 unlock it. At least in theory.