# Posix Semaphores. Why will my threads not wait at sem_wait() like they're supposed to?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, semaphore

The code in question is:

```
void insertIntoFinalArray(char * string) {
    sem_wait(&insert);
    if (finalarray == NULL) finalarray = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));
    else finalarray = (char **) realloc(finalarray, ((size_final + 1) * sizeof(char *)));

    finalarray[size_final] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(string) + 1);
    strcpy(finalarray[size_final], string);
    size_final++;
    sem_post(&insert);
}
```

insert is initialized as `sem_init(&insert, 0, 0);` EDIT: this is supposed to be `sem_init(&insert, 0, 1)` I was code stirring and just didn't set it back... it doesn't work either way.

As I understand it, the threads should wait at sem_wait() until the value is greater than zero. However, the debug shows multiple threads within the function. [image: ugggg]

So am I just not understanding what a semaphore does or ?

Edit: OS X doesn't support unnamed semaphores... However, even using `insert = sem_open("insert", O_CREAT, 1);` allows all threads to get past my sem_wait() line.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure you aren't posting somewhere else in the code because otherwise nothing is getting in there to begin with.  BTW what debugger is that?  Is it from an IDE?

Comment: no nowhere else am I posting http://pastebin.com/Q1Pdi6bw

Comment: If it is initialized to a value of zero, how would anything get past the first `sem_wait`. Something is fishy here. I'd suggest posting a complete program that shows your problem.

Comment: @wjl I originally had it as sem_init(&insert, 0, 1) but I was code stirring and hadn't switched it back... also see my other comment for the full code.

Comment: @Duck it's xcode. It's pretty nifty, actually.

Comment: Oh ok, I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4136440/63743) is your problem.  The comment about the debugger reminded me of osx.  Xcode sure looks nice though.

Comment: nope. I open it, and then unlink it, and all threads still manage to get in. 

`insert = sem_open("insert", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 1);
    sem_unlink("insert");`

Comment: Try "/insert" for the name.  And check your return codes.

Comment: @Duck that worked... why did that work?

Comment: See the the description section in the [posix spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html)  Not sure I can explain that anyway.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Duck for helping me out.

Apple gcc defines sem_init in semaphores.h, but it returns -1 - it's unimplemented. That is, you cannot have unnamed semaphores. Instead, use `sem_open(name, options, initial value);`