# OSX semaphores: Invalid argument in sem_open

Tags: macos, semaphore

While trying to open a semaphore sem_open fails. errno is 22 (), which perror describes as "Invalid argument". I've checked the format of the name (which I think is correct), as well as the flags (O_CREAT and O_EXCL seem pretty hard to mess up. What am I not seeing?

Platform is OS X 10.7. I would have preferred to use a nameless semaphore, but the [OS doesn't support sem_init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413785/sem-init-on-os-x).

```
int name_counter = 0;

// In order to create a unique semaphore, we iterate until we find a name that
// does not already exist.
do {
    char name[48] = {0};
    sprintf(name, "xyz_sem_%d", name_counter++);
    job_semaphore = sem_open(name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH, 0);
} while(errno == EEXIST);

if(0 != errno)
    perror("Error opening xyz semaphore");
assert(0 == errno);
```

I've tried both

```
sem_open(name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL);
```

and

```
sem_open(name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH, 0);
```

to open the semaphore, but get the same result with each. What am I missing?

EDIT: the version above with only two parameters is wrong- the man page says that when including O_CREAT, you must provide all 4 parameters.

EDIT2: errno is only valid when the function returns an error code. In this case, I should have looked at errno only when sem_open returned SEM_FAILED. I didn't do this, and was examining errno when a perfectly good semaphore had been returned. Problem solved.

Comment: @leebaker: did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Before trying sem_open, try sem_unlink()

Answer (score 0):

name should have a leading slash. Try put a "/" in front of name. 
ie. sprintf(name, "/xyz_sem_%d", name_counter++);

Comment: Where is it documented that semaphore names should start with a slash? Is this a convention or a hard requirement?

Comment: Not having OSX handy,  Freebsd, 'man sem_open' says .... "This implementation places strict requirements on the value of name: it
     must begin with a slash (‘/’) and contain no other slash characters.
" , On linux the same sort of thing in 'man sem_overview'  , so prolly also true for OSX

Comment: iOS/Mac OS doesn't seem to have that requirement. I'm using semaphores who's names start with an alpha and contain alphanumerics and slashes, and they work fine.