# sem_unlink permission denied

Tags: c, macos, posix

I have a school assignment where we are supposed to solve [readers-writers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem) problem. As I found earlier [sem_init is not supported on osx machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413785/sem-init-on-os-x) so I went with sem_open. However the code below does not work as expected.

```
if(sem_open(sem_reader, O_CREAT, 1, 0600) == SEM_FAILED)
    perror("sem_reader");
```

The semaphore IS created, but when I try to unlink it with following code:

```
if(sem_unlink(sem_reader) != 0)
    perror("unlink_sem_reader");
```

I get the output:

```
unlink_sem_reader: Permission denied
```

I tried to play with permissions like 0700, 0660 etc., but I always get permission denided. They are both wrapped in function and no action is taken with them. I am not sure where the problem is. My question is:

**Did I set permissions incorrectly or the problem is somewhere else?**

EDIT: Working in Xcode / 10.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you switched arguments mode and value of `sem_open`.