# SQL 3.3 xmalloc overflow example - why?

Tags: c, integer-overflow

The following example can be found in many places on the internet:

> The following code excerpt from OpenSSH 3.3 demonstrates a classic case of integer overflow:
> (bad code)
> Example Language: C

```
nresp = packet_get_int();
if (nresp > 0) {
  response = xmalloc(nresp*sizeof(char*));
  for (i = 0; i < nresp; i++) response[i] = packet_get_string(NULL);
}
```

> If nresp has the value 1073741824 and sizeof(char*) has its typical
> value of 4, then the result of the operation `nresp*sizeof(char*)`
> overflows, and the argument to xmalloc() will be 0. Most malloc()
> implementations will happily allocate a 0-byte buffer, causing the
> subsequent loop iterations to overflow the heap buffer response.

If nresp is an int and sizeof() returns a size_t, which in x86_64 is essentially unsigned long, the result should be unsigned long.  Is the problem with the above that the argument for xmalloc is an int?  Or does the example assume IA32?  If not, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you stuck wth 32-bit systems?  Are they embedded?  I'd debate your characterization of "`sizeof(char *)` has its typical value of 4" — it's 8 on 64-bit systems.  And on such systems,  `sizeof(size_t) == 8` so there isn't arithmetic overflow with the `nresp` value you quote.  A bigger problem is that the code doesn't check that the space was allocated successfully — that's an invitation for disaster.  The code should be designed so that values that are to large are eliminated before they cause trouble.  However, much code does not take such issues seriously.

Comment: I claim no originality for the quote, and I doubt that the (anonymous) person who wrote ["There is no portable code; there is only code that has been ported"](https://www.osnews.com/story/1434/syllable-team-marches-on/) in 2002 would claim any originality, either on their own behalf or on their husband's behalf.   I've quoted the [epithet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368305/how-to-test-posix-compatibility#comment13362457_10368305) on SO before.  — and I claim no originality either.

Comment: Re “which in x86_64 is a long”: Nowhere in the quoted text does it say the platform is x86_64. You have added an assumption. Quite obviously, the author of the text did not use that assumption. (Also `size_t` can never be `long`, as it must be unsigned.)

Comment: The type of `size_t` is never `long`; it is always an unsigned type.  Often it is equivalent to `unsigned long`, which may be 32-bits or 64-bits, depending on the platform.  Beware Windows 64 — `long` is still a 32-bit type, even though pointers are 64-bit types.

Comment: Yes, thanks Jonathan, question updated to "unsigned long"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler a lot of old systems did in fact have a signed `size_t`; most people today probably learn this if they read `dlmalloc`-derived sources

Comment: @o11c – Hmm.  Sice `size_t` was invented by the C89/C90 standard committee and that required `size_t` to be unsigned, it is surprising to here that there were systems where thetype was not unsigned.  Section §6.5.3.4 "The `sizeof` operator" in the [C99 Rationale](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) discusses this. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ "C89, like K&R, defined the result of the sizeof operator to be a constant of an unsigned integer type. Common implementations, and common usage, have often assumed that the resulting type is int. Old code that depends on this behavior has never been portable to implementations that define the result to be a type other than int. The C89 Committee did not feel it was proper to change the language to protect incorrect code." —
"The type of `sizeof`, whatever it is, is published (in the library header `<stddef.h>`) as
`size_t`, since it is useful for the programmer …"

Comment: @o11c That's usually handled by inventing a non-standard type `ssize_t`, as seen in various old, skunky Unix APIs.

Answer (score 1):

> If `nresp` is an `int` and `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, which in x86_64 is essentially `unsigned long`, the result should be `unsigned long`.

True, yet the product can overflow when `INT_MAX > ULONG_MAX/sizeof(char*)`.  (e.g. `int` and `unsigned long,size_t` both 32-bit.)

---

Even when `nresp > 0` and `sizeof(char*)` is a smallish value, computations like `nresp*sizeof(char*)` risk overflow given it is an `int * size_t`.

C does not specify `size_t` to be wider than `int`, although `size_t` is some *unsigned* type.  `size_t` may only have 1 more bit than `int` and overflow can occurs when `sizeof(char*)` is greater than 2.
(On select machine, `SIZE_MAX <= INT_MAX` is possible.)

Robust code prevents/detects potential overflow without making undue assumptions about the width of `size_t` and `int`.

**Simple to add a range test**

```
int nresp = packet_get_int();  
if (nresp > 0) {
    response = (unsigned) nresp > SIZE_MAX/sizeof(char*) ? NULL : xmalloc(nresp*sizeof(char*));
    if (response == NULL) {
      ; // TBD code to handle allocation failure.
    } else {
      for (i = 0; i < nresp; i++) response[i] = packet_get_string(NULL);
    }
  }
}
```

On machines where `SIZE_MAX/sizeof(char*) > UINT_MAX`, I'd expect `response = (unsigned) nresp > SIZE_MAX/sizeof(char*) ? NULL : xmalloc(nresp*sizeof(char*));` to optimize to `response = xmalloc(nresp*sizeof(char*));`

---

IMO, better as `response = (unsigned) nresp > SIZE_MAX/sizeof(char*) ? NULL : xmalloc(sizeof response[0] * (unsigned) nresp);`

Comment: OK, so it sounds like the issue has nothing to do with xmalloc(), and if size_t is a 64-bit unsigned long, and if int is 32-bits, then there would be no problem with this code.

Comment: @HangingParens Yes, If `size_t` is 64-bit and ìnt` is 32-bit and if `xmalloc()`does not return `NULL`, then no problem, today, with the original code.  Yet with simply tests, we can write code that does not depend on those _ifs_.  Your call.