# sem_getvalue() dysfunctionality in Mac OS X - C++

Tags: c++, macos, semaphore

I'm trying to implement synchronized use of a shared memory for bunch of threads in Mac OS X by semaphores.

(I just overlook the fact that Mac users have got lots of issues with initializing a semaphore and destroying it...,which can be fixed by sem_open() and sem_unlink()):D

But apparently for getting semaphore's current value there's nothing but sem_getvalue() which hasn't been implemented in mac os x.

Any suggestion for someone that doesn't have linux OS running and should upload his homework in hours??!:)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are asking, *"how can I work around the absence of `sem_getvalue()` on OS X?"*

I can think of three approaches:

First (and best, in my opinion) redesign your program so that the current value of the semaphore is never needed.  After all, [as the documentation warns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_getvalue.html), the value reported by `sem_getvalue` isn't necessarily accurate by the time it is received.

Second, if necessary, wrap the POSIX semaphore functions and keep your own count.  Every `sem_t` can be adorned by a counter and a mutex protecting that counter.  Your implementation probably will have (and probably should have!) the same caveat as `sem_getvalue`, that is, the count can't be trusted to be accurate once it is retrieved.

Third, and least palatable in my opinion, switch to the older and more complicated [SysV semaphore IPC](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/semctl.html) interface.  That implements something analogous to `sem_getvalue`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,actually I want current value of semaphore just for debugging and nothing more;is there a way to find out the value while debugging??if so it would be great!