# Why sem_open doesn't return the same value for the same name?

Tags: c, macos, posix, semaphore, darwin

I'm running the program below, and as per [sem_open's man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sem_open.2.html) :

> If a process makes repeated calls to `sem_open()`, with the same name
>   argument, the same descriptor is returned for each successful call,
>   unless `sem_unlink()` has been called on the semaphore in the interim.

I would expect `sem1` and `sem2` to be equal but seems like that they are not. The program prints `semaphores are not equal` to stdout.

#### Program:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char *sem_name = "/sem";
    sem_t *sem1, *sem2;
    sem1 = sem_open(sem_name, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
    sem2 = sem_open(sem_name, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);

    if (sem1 == SEM_FAILED || sem2 == SEM_FAILED) {
        printf("SEM_VALUE_MAX is %ud\n", SEM_VALUE_MAX);
        err(1, "SEM_FAILED");
    }

    if (sem1 != sem2) {
        printf("semaphores are not equal\n");
        return (2);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Some additional information about my environment:

```
(jalcazar@mac ~)$ uname -a 
Darwin mac.local 13.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Also *[The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html)* says:

> If a process makes multiple successful calls to `sem_open()` with the
>   same value for name, the same semaphore address shall be returned for
>   each such successful call.

**I feel like I'm missing something very basic but haven't figured out what is it.**

**Any hint?**

**Edit:**
A slightly modified version works as expected on *Ubuntu 13.04* and *FreeBSD 10.0*. 
It prints `semaphores are not equal` on *OpenBSD 5.5* but since only `bbf44dc795572df9c53f06b4ba06c4e51d8660a7502b8a0cd0b2b43081af314f.sem` is in `/tmp` it would make sense to assume that it is the same semaphore.

Comment: The code requires some tweaking to make it compile on Linux, but I concur with your findings: Mac OS X 10.9.3 returns the values 0x3 and 0x4 (which are manifestly different), but Ubuntu 14.04 returns the same (large) hexadecimal address.  The manual page does not match the actual behaviour.  The discrepancy alone means there's a bug somewhere.  I'd say the problem is in the implementation, not in the manual page which conforms to POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a `sem_t*` with `==` to determine if it's the same semaphore. `sem1 == sem2` will check if the twp pointers are equal in the sense they both came from the same sem_open() call, not if they refer to the same underlying semaphore. The wording of the OSX man page sounds a bit dishonest in this regard.

There are however no functions or operators you can use to check if two `sem_t*` refers to the same semaphore object, albeit if you add these lines, it's reasonalbe to exepct they are if the output is 2:

```
int val = 9;
sem_post(sem1);
sem_post(sem1);
sem_getvalue(sem2, &val);
printf("sem2 value=%d\n", val);
```

Think of the `sem_t*` just as a handle that might refer to the same underlying semaphore.  This is quite similar to calling open() twice on the same file, you get two different file descriptors back but they still refer to the same file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, since `sem_getvalue` is broken on Mac OS X, I think your code is not going to provide hints whether `sem1` and `sem2` refer to the same underlying semaphore. See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655153/sem-getvalue-dysfunctionality-in-mac-os-x-c and
http://heldercorreia.com/blog/semaphores-in-mac-os-x

Comment: I wouldn't characterize ENOSYS as "broken".

Comment: As was just edited into the question, POSIX also states that the same address should be returned, so it seems that the OSX man page matches POSIX, but the behavior doesn't

Comment: The first paragraph (or the first couple of sentences of it) are bogus.