# Control the order of the threads ending

Tags: c, pthreads

I have 4 Threads (Thread_A - Thread_D). I want them to end in the order A, B, C, D. It must be solved with semaphores.

Whats wrong with my code? In most cases it's fine, but sometimes it's in the wrong order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

void* thread_A (void *arg);
void* thread_B (void *arg);
void* thread_C (void *arg);
void* thread_D (void *arg);

typedef struct sem_package {
    sem_t* sem1;
    sem_t* sem2;
} sem_package;

void* thread_A (void *arg) {
    sem_t* sem = (sem_t*) arg;

    int random_sleep = (int) (500 + ((random()) / RAND_MAX) * 2000);
    struct timespec sleep_time;
    sleep_time.tv_sec = random_sleep / 1000;
    sleep_time.tv_nsec = (random_sleep % 1000) * 1000000;

    nanosleep(&sleep_time, NULL);

    sem_post(sem);  //unblock B
    printf("\nA\n");
    return NULL;
}

void* thread_B (void *arg) {
    sem_package* pack = (sem_package*) arg;

    int random_sleep = (int) (500 + ((random()) / RAND_MAX) * 2000);
    struct timespec sleep_time;
    sleep_time.tv_sec = random_sleep / 1000;
    sleep_time.tv_nsec = (random_sleep % 1000) * 1000000;

    nanosleep(&sleep_time, NULL);

    sem_wait(pack->sem1);   //wait for A
    sem_post(pack->sem2);   //unblock C
    printf("\nB\n");
    return NULL;    
}

void* thread_C (void *arg) {
    sem_package* pack = (sem_package*) arg;

    int random_sleep = (int) (500 + ((random()) / RAND_MAX) * 2000);
    struct timespec sleep_time;
    sleep_time.tv_sec = random_sleep / 1000;
    sleep_time.tv_nsec = (random_sleep % 1000) * 1000000;

    nanosleep(&sleep_time, NULL);

    sem_wait(pack->sem2);   //wait for B
    sem_post(pack->sem1);   //unblock D
    printf("\nC\n");
    return NULL;
}

void* thread_D (void *arg) {
    sem_t* sem = (sem_t*) arg;

    int random_sleep = (int) (500 + ((random()) / RAND_MAX) * 2000);
    struct timespec sleep_time;
    sleep_time.tv_sec = random_sleep / 1000;
    sleep_time.tv_nsec = (random_sleep % 1000) * 1000000;

    nanosleep(&sleep_time, NULL);

    sem_wait(sem);  //wait for C
    printf("\nD\n");

    return NULL;
}

int main () {
    srandom((unsigned int) time(NULL)); 

    pthread_t threadA, threadB, threadC, threadD;

    sem_t sem_A_B;
    sem_t sem_C_D;
    sem_t sem_B_C;

    sem_init(&sem_A_B,0,0);
    sem_init(&sem_C_D,0,0);
    sem_init(&sem_B_C,0,0);

    struct sem_package pack1;
    pack1.sem1=&sem_A_B;
    pack1.sem2=&sem_B_C;

    struct sem_package pack2;
    pack2.sem1=&sem_C_D;
    pack2.sem2=&sem_B_C;

    pthread_create(&threadA,NULL,thread_A,&sem_A_B);
    pthread_create(&threadB,NULL,thread_B,&pack1);
    pthread_create(&threadC,NULL,thread_C,&pack2);
    pthread_create(&threadD,NULL,thread_D,&sem_C_D);

    long m;
    pthread_join(threadD, (void **) &m);

    sem_destroy(&sem_A_B);
    sem_destroy(&sem_B_C);
    sem_destroy(&sem_C_D);

    pthread_detach(threadA);
    pthread_detach(threadB);
    pthread_detach(threadC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "sometime its in wrong order". How do you know?

Comment: @n.m. because of the printf in the functions. Yea its true , there could happen an sem_post and right after it could loose his turn and another thread could start working because of the post

Comment: One, important trick with mutiple threads is to design so that such things don't matter.  @n.m. has alredy pointed out how difficult it is to ensure such things.  Best to not bother trying.

Comment: `printf` is not synchronized in any way and output can appear in any order.

Comment: @MartinJames of course you are right, but i have to do it because of the school..

Comment: what can i use to check in which order they ended? Is printf before post enough?

Comment: This is tangential to the issue of the order in which the threads finish, but one thing that's wrong is that you don't add the thread name to the `struct sem_package` so that you can have just a single thread function that gets all the information it needs from the arguments passed in.  You'd have a little cleanup work to do, but it would reduce your code quite dramatically.

Comment: @Muco : you could try pointing `pthread_create` to a proxy function that actually calls the real thread function saved in a `struct` passed into it as a parameter. This way, you could set up a debugger to break when leaving that proxy function. However, the execution order may be different when running under a debugger...

Comment: Printing plus `fflush()` after `sem_wait()` and before `sem_post()` would give you a decent chance.

Comment: If `main` waits for thread A to finish with `pthread_join`, and then posts the semaphore for B, then you would know that A was completely finished before B.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler did exactly what you said, now it's always in the same order. I don't understand why, but it works.

Comment: It works because (1) the threads can't print until they've received the 'go' signal from their predecessor, if they have a predecessor, and (2) only one thread can be printing at a time because they print when they have permission to go and before they grant the next thread permission to go.  I think you could drop the `fflush()`; they're all using the same stream, one at a time in sequence, so the output should be deterministically interleaved in the correct order even without the `fflush()`.

Comment: After a bit of checking, the `fflush()` calls seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

In the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092445/control-the-order-of-the-threads-ending#comment61729088_37092445), I noted:

> This is tangential to the issue of the order in which the threads finish, but one thing that's wrong is that you don't add the thread name to the `struct sem_package` so that you can have just a single thread function that gets all the information it needs from the arguments passed in. You'd have a little cleanup work to do, but it would reduce your code quite dramatically.

I also [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092445/control-the-order-of-the-threads-ending#comment61729116_37092445):

> Printing plus `fflush()` after `sem_wait()` and before `sem_post()` would give you a decent chance [of getting the thread termination messages printed in the correct order].

To which [Muco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698350/muco) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092445/control-the-order-of-the-threads-ending#comment61729516_37092445):

> [I] did exactly what you said, now it's always in the same order. I don't understand why, but it works.

And I [responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092445/control-the-order-of-the-threads-ending#comment61731716_37092445):

> It works because (1) the threads can't print until they've received the 'go' signal from their predecessor, if they have a predecessor, and (2) only one thread can be printing at a time because they print when they have permission to go and before they grant the next thread permission to go.

I mentioned the possibility of not using `fflush()`, but that seems to be a bad idea (experimenting with GCC 6.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.4).  I have not yet worked out why the `fflush()` calls are necessary (but see section on 'Always check for errors' below).

Here's some code that implements one thread function that serves for all.  It uses a C99 feature (designated initializers) to initialize the time structure.  The `#pragma` at the top suppresses the warnings about `sem_init()` and `sem_destroy()` being deprecated on Mac OS X (see [Why are `sem_init()`, `sem_getvalue()`, `sem_destroy()` deprecated on Mac OS X — and what replaces them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736618/why-are-sem-init-sem-getvalue-sem-destroy-deprecated-on-mac-os-x-and-w) for the details).

```
/* Pragma needed on Mac OS X to suppress warnings about sem_init() and sem_destroy() */
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

static void *thread_function(void *arg);

typedef struct sem_package
{
    sem_t *sem1;
    sem_t *sem2;
    char  *name;
} sem_package;

static
void *thread_function(void *arg)
{
    sem_package *pack = (sem_package *)arg;

    int random_sleep = (int)(500 + ((random()) / RAND_MAX) * 2000);
    struct timespec sleep_time = { .tv_sec  = random_sleep / 1000,
                                   .tv_nsec = (random_sleep % 1000) * 1000000
                                 };

    nanosleep(&sleep_time, NULL);

    if (pack->sem1)
        sem_wait(pack->sem1);   // wait for predecessor
    printf("\n%s\n", pack->name);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (pack->sem2)
        sem_post(pack->sem2);   // unblock successor
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    srandom((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    pthread_t threadA, threadB, threadC, threadD;

    sem_t sem_A_B;
    sem_t sem_C_D;
    sem_t sem_B_C;

    sem_init(&sem_A_B, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem_C_D, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&sem_B_C, 0, 0);

    struct sem_package pack1 = { NULL,     &sem_A_B, "A" };
    struct sem_package pack2 = { &sem_A_B, &sem_B_C, "B" };
    struct sem_package pack3 = { &sem_B_C, &sem_C_D, "C" };
    struct sem_package pack4 = { &sem_C_D, NULL,     "D" };

    pthread_create(&threadA, NULL, thread_function, &pack1);
    pthread_create(&threadB, NULL, thread_function, &pack2);
    pthread_create(&threadC, NULL, thread_function, &pack3);
    pthread_create(&threadD, NULL, thread_function, &pack4);

    void *vp;
    pthread_join(threadD, &vp);

    sem_destroy(&sem_A_B);
    sem_destroy(&sem_B_C);
    sem_destroy(&sem_C_D);

    pthread_detach(threadA);
    pthread_detach(threadB);
    pthread_detach(threadC);

    printf("\nAll done\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
A

B

C

D

All done
```

#### Always check for errors

To try and work out why I was seeing erratic behaviour without `fflush()`, I added relatively comprehensive error checking on the system calls.  The initial run was a sober reminder of why it is important to check the return values from system calls:

```
$ ./pthread-37
pthread-37: sem_init(): error (78) Function not implemented
$
```

Frankly, I'd rather the system didn't provide the entry point that says "I'll pretend it's here but it isn't really here".  This is an odd meaning for 'deprecated' too; normally, that means "it is present (and works) but it may go missing in the future".  However, there is at least a solid explanation for why the semaphores didn't seem to be enforcing order — they don't exist, so they can't enforce the order.

All this applies to the Mac.  When I tried it in an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM with GCC 4.8.4, then the code works correctly — even with the error checking and without the `fflush()` calls.  This is the sane behaviour.

Object lessons:

- Check return values from system calls.
- Mac OS X does not implement `sem_init()`.

Comment: You moved `sem_post` after `printf`. WIth that change, `fflush` should no longer be necessary,

Comment: @EmployedRussian: I agree, but…When I run the code without the `fflush()` on a Mac, I get the output `A B D C All done` (spread over multiple lines).  That may indicate a flaw in the Mac OS X implementation of pthreads, but it is empirically what I got on the first (re)run without `fflush()`.  As I said, I don't understand why the `fflush()` was necessary, but it seems to be necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yesterday i only tried with flush, but now i also tried without the flush(). It also works without flush() for me on ubuntu. Also thanks for the code below.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: See my update — Mac OS X has a dummy entry point for `sem_init()` which simply returns 'not implemented' as an error.  Not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> I want them to end in the order A, B, C, D.

You have to be a bit more precise on what you mean by that. Consider the following possible operation interleaving (time increases from top to bottom):

```
Thread A                      Thread B
sem_post(sem); //unblock B
                              sem_wait(pack->sem1);   //wait for A
                              sem_post(pack->sem2);   //unblock C
                              printf("\nB\n");
                              return NULL;    
printf("\nA\n");
return NULL;
```

If above interleaving were to take place, you will have `B` printed before `A` and thread B "ending" (reaching `return`) before thread A.

Now consider this other interleaving:

```
Thread A                      Thread B
sem_post(sem); //unblock B
                              sem_wait(pack->sem1);   //wait for A
                              sem_post(pack->sem2);   //unblock C
                              printf("\nB\n");
printf("\nA\n");
return NULL;
                              return NULL;
```

Here you *still* have `B` printed before `A`, but now thread A "ends" before thread B does. You can also have `A` printed before `B` with thread A ending before or after thread B (I leave the interleaving as an exercise to you).

So what's the answer?

What you are probably interested is not the "thread A ends before thread B", but "thread A ends its *useful* work before thread B". If we define useful work as printing the `A` or `B`, then to fix your problem you have to move the `printf` calls before you wake up another thread.