# Unable to make an Producer-Consumer instance with list in c++

Tags: c++, pthreads, producer-consumer

guys. I am learning about the Producer-Consumer Problem. My professor gave us an example code using a classical `int array` to share resources between the two threads. It works as expected, however, I wanted to try it using `std:list` class from C++ and it doesn't work as expected. The consumer seems not to respect `sem_wait(&full);` so it tries to consume many times when there is nothing in the shared list.

Original code with array buffer

```cpp
#include    <pthread.h>
#include    <semaphore.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <unistd.h>

#define    N 2
#define    TRUE 1

int    buffer[N], in = 0, out = 0;
sem_t  empty, full, mutexC, mutexP;

void *producer(void *arg) {

   while(TRUE) {
       sleep(rand()%5);

       sem_wait(&empty);
       sem_wait(&mutexP);
    
       buffer[in] = rand() % 100;
       printf("Producing buffer[%d] = %d\n", in, buffer[in]);
       in= (in+1) % N;

       sem_post(&mutexP);
       sem_post(&full);
       
   }
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {

   while(TRUE) {
       
       sleep(rand()%5);
       sem_wait(&full);
       sem_wait(&mutexC);
       
       printf("Consuming buffer[%d] = %d\n", out, buffer[out]);
       out = (out+1) % N;
       
       sem_post(&mutexC);
       sem_post(&empty);
       
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]) {
    pthread_t cons, prod;

    sem_init(&mutexC, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&mutexP, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, N);
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    
    pthread_create(&prod, NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&cons, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

My implementation with list:

```cpp
#include    <pthread.h>
#include    <semaphore.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <iostream>
#include    <list>

#define    TRUE 1
#define    N 2

using namespace std;

list<int> sharedList;

sem_t  empty, full, mutexC, mutexP;

void *producer(void *arg) {

   while(TRUE) {
       
       sleep(rand()%5);

       sem_wait(&empty);
       sem_wait(&mutexP);
       int prod = rand() % 100;
       cout << "producing: " << prod << endl;
       sharedList.push_back(prod);

       sem_post(&mutexP);
       sem_post(&full);
       
   }
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {

   while(TRUE) {
      
       sleep(rand()%5);

       sem_wait(&full);
       sem_wait(&mutexC);
       
       if (!sharedList.empty()) {
           cout << "consuming: ";
           cout << sharedList.front() << endl;
           sharedList.pop_front();
       } else {
           cout << "not possible to consume" << endl;
       }
       sem_post(&mutexC);
       sem_post(&empty);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]) {
    pthread_t cons, prod;

    sem_init(&mutexC, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&mutexP, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, N);
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    
    pthread_create(&prod, NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&cons, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The - unexpected - logs from my implementation:

```
producing: 73
consuming: 73
not possible to consume
producing: 44
consuming: 44
producing: 9
producing: 65
consuming: 9
producing: 87
consuming: 65
consuming: producing: 29
87
not possible to consume
consuming: 29
producing: 9
producing: 60
consuming: 9
producing: 78
```

Can somebody explain to me what is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, note that in both programs:

- with only one producer ever contending for semaphore `mutexP`, that semaphore serves no useful purpose.
- Likewise, with only one consumer ever contending for semaphore `mutexC`, that serves no useful purpose either.

Now, consider what purpose is served in your first program by initializing semaphore `empty` with value 2 instead of value 1: I presume that you will agree that doing so allows the producer to run concurrently with the consumer, one position ahead.  This is ok because **accesses to different array elements do not conflict.**

But when your storage is a `std::list` instead of an array, it is *not* ok for two threads to manipulate it concurrently if one of them modifies it.  There are several complementary ways to look at it, among them:

- a `std::list` is a single object, access to which must be synchronized, whereas an array is merely an aggregate of its elements, not a distinct object of its own as far as synchronization requirements are concerned.
- a `std::list` has members -- maintaining the current list size, for example -- that are used by all manipulations, access to which must be synchronized.

However you choose to look at it, you must ensure that the `std::list` cannot be accessed concurrently by two threads if one of those threads modifies it.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the inutility of `mutexP` and `mutexC` in the samples given! The intention was, as soon as it started working properly, to create more consumers and more producers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Follow up

Although the second code does have its errors, it turns out that macOS *does* ignore `sem_wait()`. I tried to initialize all the semaphores with 0 expecting the program to enter a deadlock, but it actually didn't. So, if running on macOS, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452182/7969193)

Answer (score 0):

*rand() % 6* can generate some interesting sequences; so the spurious wakeup *not possible to consume* is to be expected.

Beyond that, the only confusing bit is:

```
consuming: producing: 29
87
not possible to consume
```

Which isn't that confusing; the io statements interleave.  If they didn't, you would see this as:

```
consuming: 87
producing: 29
not possible to consume
```

where the last statement would be a result of checking the condition just before the producer created *29*.