# Boost semaphore exception

Tags: c++, exception, boost, fedora

We are developing a set of applications and some shared libraries for common functionality.
In one of the libraries, we use Boost Interprocess semaphores for thread synchronization.

The problem is that, in one application the Boost Interprocess semaphores work fine, but in another application they throw an exception (what(): Function not implemented; errno: ENOSYS).
The main difference between the two applications is that the failing application has a Qt-based GUI, while the other application does not have a UI.

Both applications are (dynamically) linked with librt.so.1 and libpthread.so.0
This has been tested on Fedora 14, with kernel 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686.

The usual reasons for ENOSYS do not seem to apply, because it works with one application, but not with the other while both applications run on the same system.

We are using the `boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore.timed_wait()` function.

Comment: googling `+ENOSYS interprocess_semaphore timed_wait` gave this as the second hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641126/posix-semaphores-on-mac-os-x-sem-timedwait-alternative

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the error with a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/)? I realize that this might be difficult, but sometimes I have solved an issue by iteratively removing more and more of an app, just until the error disappears. Another thing that might help you get a good answer is to add more context. Add the exact line that throws the exception, for example.